# One row, multiple inputs?

Tags: pascal

In pascal, as you might know, you can assign multiple variables values in one single line (as long as you have variables to catch them in):

```
var x, y, z: integer;
readln(x, y, z, etc...);
```

But what if i wanted to have only one variable, which would sequentially recieve those values which sit, practically, in the void?

Let me explain:

```
Number of values?
>3 (for example)

Insert values:
4 6 9
```

Now, these values, would periodically be assigned to 'a' for example, and once i'm done with the number 4, i want it to recieve 6, and 9 afterwards. Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: You are looking for an array. And a counter.

Comment: Don't arrays have limits though? My row of numbers is (theoretically) infinite.

Comment: If the row of numbers can be infinite, you would have to a function that produces the numbers. Assign your variable `a` from the function value(s).

Comment: Well, you're never going to be able to process an infinite number of numbers at the same time.  Although I agree with @AndreasRejbrand, the best way to deal with this may depend on whether what you need to do with the number you're currently processing depends on the value of any of the previous numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In Extended Pascal, ISO 10206, you can do the following:

```
program lists(input, output);

procedure processList(length: integer);
var
    list: array[1..length] of integer;
var
    n: integer;
begin
    writeLn('Insert ', length:1, ' values:');
    for n := 1 to length do
    begin
        read(list[n]);
    end;
    
    { Here you can further process `list` }
end;

var
    n: integer;
begin
    writeLn('Number of values?');
    readLn(n);
    processList(n);
end.
```

A better implementation uses schemata for this task:

```
program lists(input, output);

type
    list(length: integer) = array[1..length] of integer;

var
    n: integer;
    l: ^list;
begin
    writeLn('Number of values?');
    readLn(n);
    
    { dynamically allocate memory for `l` }
    new(l, n);
    
    writeLn('Insert values:');
    for n := 1 to l^.length do
    begin
        read(l^[n]);
    end;
    
    dispose(l);
end.
```

At compile-time undiscriminated schema data types can only be handled via pointers, which is always a little unpleasant for us programmers, but it works.